# Adjective describing something to be for those with special knowledge or interests

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Some months ago I watched a video on a tech YouTube channel (Level1Techs, if you were curious) and Randall used a word like in the following sentence:

> I did a video about it, but it's a bit *<blank>*

I Googled the word, and basically it meant something targeted at or interesting to only those with special knowledge or interests.

Any ideas? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: -1 questions that ask us to guess are deprecated here

Comment: Insider. // Write to the content provider and ask!

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking us what word you heard on a video once? Why can you not go back and listen to it again since you seem to know what channel it was on?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (1) it's asking us to guess what word was used in a video description; (2) any answer would merely be 'opinion-based'.

Comment: @Spagirl They have tons and tons of videos, and many of them are multi hour. It would be a huge undertaking to rake through them all. How else than asking here would you suggest I ever find the word?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Could you be thinking of *esoteric*?

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/esoteric): esoteric: understood by or meant for only the select few who have special knowledge or interest. (Dictionary.com)

*technical* is also a possibility but I think that's one that would be easy enough to remember.

Comment: YES!!! Thank you, that's a 2 month itch finally scratched

Answer (score 15):

The first word that popped into my mind is *niche*:

> denoting or relating to products, services, or interests that appeal to a small, specialized section of the population

source: *New Oxford American Dictionary*

Answer (score 9):

> I did a video about it, but it's a bit *arcane*?

Arcane: Understood by few; mysterious or secret. ([Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/arcane))

Otherwise maybe *[enigmatic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enigmatic)*?

Answer (score 7):

I like *niche* best, but if your video was full of jargon and was for **specialists**, you could say it was *technical*.

> **technical**
>
> 1. belonging or pertaining to an art, science, or the like:
>      technical skill.
> 2. peculiar to or characteristic of a particular art, science, profession, trade, etc.:
>      technical details.
> 3. using terminology or treating subject matter in a manner peculiar to a particular field, as a writer or a book:
>      a technical report.
>
> **specialist** a person who devotes himself or herself to one subject or to one particular branch of a subject or pursuit.

(Source: Dictionary.com)

Comment: I think *technical* is the best, at least for STEM-type subjects.

Comment: I'd say that if it was for specialists then you could easily describe the video as specialist.

Answer (score 2):

- ***esoteric, specialized/specialist, niche*** are the terms generally used
- ***obscure***
- ***recherche, arcane*** if you want a literary flourish

Answer (score 2):

> and basically it meant something targeted at or interesting to only those with special knowledge or interests.

People with special knowledge or interests are *specialists*, so the word you're looking for should be *specialistic*.

> Definition of **specialist** from [Merriam-Webster on line](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specialist)
>
> 1. one who specializes in a particular occupation, practice, or branch of learning
> 2. an enlisted rank in the U.S. Army corresponding to the grade of corporal; also :  any of several former enlisted ranks corresponding
>      to the grades of sergeant through sergeant major
> 3. an organism (as a bird) specialized especially in food or habitat

**Specialistic**, from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/specialistic):

> *specialistic* `[spesh-uh-lis-tik]` adjective
>
> 1. pertaining to or characteristic of specialists or specialism.
>
> Origin of specialistic
>   1880-1885
>   1880-85; specialist + -ic

Comment: Specialistic (adj) is AmE, specialist (adj) is BrE, just for reference. Interestingly I've never ever heard "specialistic" despite working for a large American engineering company for many years - always "specialist".

Answer (score 0):

I agree that *niche* is the best choice, but another word they might possibly have used is *boutique*.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).